# Missing network param from emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I try to change the network type from android emulator. From the official android documentation (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html), i want to use network to change LTE/UMTS/GPRS network type. I create a new emulator from the last Android Studio 2.2 and connect with telnet. I run the help command (after authentication) and I get :

```
Android console command help:

help|h|?         print a list of commands
crash            crash the emulator instance
kill             kill the emulator instance
quit|exit        quit control session
redir            manage port redirections
power            power related commands
event            simulate hardware events
avd              control virtual device execution
finger           manage emulator fingerprint
geo              Geo-location commands
sms              SMS related commands
cdma             CDMA related commands
gsm              GSM related commands
rotate           rotate the screen by 90 degrees
```

I don't see network as explain in the documentation and when I try to run a network command, I get an error... Anybody have already met this issue ? Any idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems to be delete in last versions of the emulator. I hope the android team will implement this feature soon.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=emulator%20network%20unknown&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=-id%20-stars&id=204888